help in finding the original shloka
Namaste everyone
I dont know where but i found this sanskrit shlok while i was searching about srimad bhagwat geeta
i dont know sanskrit but i will try my best to write , i found this very beautiful
na paapey paritapaapa sahate
it was something very similar and luckily the translation was also there ,
it was something like
we shouldnot do evil to justify another evil
Forgive me if i have misquoted anything wrong here ,
please , help me where is this sanskrit shlok from , and what is the complete shlok
so I searched and finally found , it was here
in the mahabharata
aaranya parva 207 , 45th shlok
न पापे प्रतिपाप: स्यात्‌ साधुरेव सदा भवेत्‌ |
आत्मनैव हतः पापो य: पापं कर्तुमिच्छति ।। ४५ ।।


please post the shloka as an answer, along with URL to the Devanagari source and English translation.  thank you. @test132342

so I searched and finally found , it was here in the mahabharata aaranya parva 207 , 45th shlok
Here it is
न पापे प्रतिपाप: स्यात्‌ साधुरेव सदा भवेत्‌ |
आत्मनैव हतः पापो य: पापं कर्तुमिच्छति ।। ४५ ।।

the translation is in hindi though , but i got the translation here , i just translated hindi to english via google translate
If someone misbehaves with you, do not do bad things to him in return. Always behave well with everyone. The sinner who wants to harm others is himself
is destroyed

